# Accordion Does not work

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, mathml

I have this Accordion in my website which works fine on computers but as i decrease screen it stops working and does not expand on clicking, i have seen everywhere and i have no idea why is this happening as it seems to work fine on medium and large screen.

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="panel-group resize" id="accordion">

        <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterSum" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br />
                <div class="panel panel-default resize" style="background-color: #ebe7e7; color: #000000;padding:10px;border-top-left-radius:20px;">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href='<%# "#" + Eval("SumID") %>'>
                        <div class="resize">
                            <h4 class="panel-title resize" style="padding:10px">

                                <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" ForeColor="#000000" Text='<%# Eval("ProblemStatement") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div id='<%# Eval("SumID") %>' class="panel-collapse collapse resize">
                        <div class="panel-body resize" style="background-color:white; padding:10px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSolution" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Solution") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <h5 style="padding:10px">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%# "Ans.: " + Eval("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </div>
</div>
```

> **Note: Accordion contains mathml**

Comment: shrinking makes me thing of `CSS`, which in turn makes me think of `media queries`. can you please share the relevant `CSS`?

Comment: `<style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .resize {
                font-size: 2em;
            }
        }
    </style>`   @Ted

Comment: is that it? maybe there's another css class in the bootstrap css that affect the Acordion classes

Comment: how to find out what is causing the problem from bootstrap css? @Ted

Comment: use the browser's developer tools and inspect the computed css for each element in and around the acordion

Comment: thanks i will see  that @Ted

Comment: I know it doesn't, the html elements are still there though. Open the webpage with Chrome, right click on where the accordion is supposes to be and click Inspect